# How to correctly place blocks using flex (CSS) to have result like in my mockup

Tags: css, flexbox, stylus

[image: mockup]

I need to place some ad block among image blocks (like in the mockup), and I don't understand how to place it.  When I placed the ad block inside, the image blocks don't align to that block. Can someone give me advice?

I am using Jade with Stylus.  Here is my code:

```
block header-bottom
    .main
        - for (var i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
            if i == 0
                .main__post_first
                    img.main__banner.main__banner_big(src="../source/images/main-image.png" alt="foo")
            else
                .main__post
                    img.main__banner.main__banner_small(src="../source/images/main-image.png" alt="foo")
        - }
    //- .main
```

And here are my styles:

```
.main 
    display -moz-box       
    display -ms-flexbox   
    display -webkit-box    
    display -webkit-flex   
    display flex
    flex-direction row
    flex-wrap wrap 
    justify-content flex-start
    align-items flex-start
    align-content flex-start
    margin-top  10px
    &__adv 
        width 160px
        height 220px
        border 1px solid black
        box-sizing border-box
    &__post
        width auto
        height: 48px
        margin-right 5px
        &_first
            width 100%
            height 202px
            margin-bottom 5px
    &__post:nth-child(5)
        flex-grow 2 
        &_nomargin
            margin-right 0
            height 52px
    &__banner
        width 100%
        &_small
            height 48px
            width auto
        &_big
            height 202px
```

And this is what I have on browser already:

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap{
  width: 551px;
}
.ad-block{
  border: 2px solid #000;
  float: right;
  height: 320px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 220px;
}
.block{
  border: 2px solid #000;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="ad-block">
<span>Ad block</span>
  </div>
  <div class="block"><span>image block</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>image block</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>image block</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>image block</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>image block</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>image block</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>image block</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>image block</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>image block</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>image block</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>image block</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>image block</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>image block</span></div>
  <div class="block"><span>image block</span></div>
</div>
```